# How to set checked radio button state . not using radio group

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I have 2 fragments - Fragment A and Fragment B. In Fragment RadioButton is set on RecyclerView. When I have click on radio button and then go to Fragment B. After that when we move again on Fragment A then radio button is showing Unselected.
I am not usin Radio Group.
 thanks.

Comment: can you post your model class and adapter class ?

Answer (score 0):

```
radioButton.isChecked();
radioButton.setChecked(true/false);
```